# jQuery: slideDown undesirably instant with no animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ria

I've written a short method to append rows to a table. It is as follows:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/* Append a row to the documentation heading table. */
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
function append_heading(heading, style, default_content, node_enabled, leaf_enabled)
{
    // Grab the table body.
    var tbody = $("#headings_table_body");

    // Generate our cells.
    var headingCell = $('<td class="heading_column"></td>');
    var styleCell = $('<td class="style_column"></td>');
    var defaultCell = $('<td class="default_column"></td>');
    var nodesCell = $('<td class="nodes_column ticked"></td>');
    var leavesCell = $('<td class="leaves_column ticked"></td>');

    // Fill in various cells.
    headingCell.append(heading);
    styleCell.append(style);
    defaultCell.append(default_content);

    // Tick some cells cross the others.
    if(node_enabled)
    {
        nodesCell.addClass("ticked");
    }

    else
    {
        nodesCell.addClass("crossed");
    }

    if(leaf_enabled)
    {
        leavesCell.addClass("ticked");
    }

    else
    {
        leavesCell.addClass("crossed");
    }

    // Add all the cells to one big row.
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>")
        .append(headingCell)
        .append(styleCell)
        .append(defaultCell)
        .append(nodesCell)
        .append(leavesCell);

    // Append the row to the table.
    tbody.append(tr);

    $(tr).hide();
    $(tr).slideDown("slow");
}
```

It appends the rows as expected, all nicely filled out and styled. The problem is, slideDown doesn't animate: It's current behaviour is analogous to me calling hide() and show(), it simply appears. How can I get this to animate correctly? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the related code (e.g. the HTML and the code to call your function)?

Comment: FYI, in the last part of your code, `tr` is already a jQuery object.  You don't need to wrap it in another jQuery object for the last two lines.  Not likely what is causing your problem, but something you should clean up.  You can just do `tr.hide()` and `tr.slideDown("slow")`.

Comment: I'm slowly adding that now. There's quite a lot of css in and around the effect, I'm hesitant to add too much at once so as not to confuse the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, I picked up on that about 30 seconds ago - a copy paste error :).

Comment: @Domenic Yeah, maybe the wrong choice of words. Athough, in my defense, I'm a C++ developer 99% of the time so my sense of perspective might be a bit warped. Also explains my Allman style indentation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is NOT able to animate tables directly. All that you need is to wrap the content of each td cell in the row into div with display:none and make slideDown animation for them! To make you life easier :)))

```
 tr.find('td').wrapInner('<div style="display: none;" />');
 tr.appendTo(tbody);
 tr.find('td > div')
             .slideDown('slow', function(){
                  var $set = $(this);
                  $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
             });
```

If you want to animate the whole table, it should be placed into div with animation applied to that div.

Comment: Interesting answer, I'll test this out and report back :).

Comment: Ah, fantastic! thank you very much, and the little snippet you provided dropped straight in, just perfect.

Comment: @LiamM         I had the same problem once and found the reason and the solution )

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because it does not know the height of the appended TR, try explicitly defining the height of the TR in your CSS or amend the code to do

```
$(tr).height($(tr).height());
$(tr).hide();
$(tr).slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your reasoning makes sense to me, however it didn't work.